# Is it possible to have multiple directives on the same HTML element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to have two different directives on the same HTML element?

`<div directiveone directivetwo></div>`

or will that cause scope issues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can and it's fairly common.  The only potential issue with scope is you can't have multiple new scopes on the same element.  Per the angular docs: "If multiple directives on the same element request a new scope, only one new scope is created."  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: What if I have `directivetwo` in the HTML for the template for `directiveone`?

Comment: Instead of on the original div?  Or also?

Comment: Inside the original `div`

Comment: Do you have an example of what you'd like to do?  It really depends on the specifics.