# Is it possible to apply multiple AngularJS controllers on the same element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to apply multiple AngularJS controllers on the same element ?

Comment: You can nest the second controller at the first and call then as one. Or you could make a third file that is composed by the other two. This answer is from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/r294h-v2Iys - Hoskins, Jim

Comment: @klauskpm, sometimes it is necessary.  For example, let's say you have a controllers hierarchy (A -> B -> C) nested.  The info you want to set on the page's `<title>` is in controller C.  Where do you put that controller?  Of course, there is `<html>`, there is `<head>` and there is the `<title>`, but you may not want to instantiate another instance of a controller just for this purposes, as it may be expensive.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*No*, you cannot apply two controllers to the same element, but you can apply multiple directives. And directives can have controllers.

```
app.directive('myDirective1', function() {
return {
controller: function(scope) {
  //directive controller
  }
 };
});

app.directive('myDirective2', function() {
return {
controller: function(scope) {
  //directive controller
  }
 };
});
```

and in the HTML:

```
<div myDirective1 myDirective2></div>
```

And as mentioned in the comments below, the two controllers could share the same scope, which is often the desired effect; one of the two controller can request a new scope, but you cannot have two new scopes;

> the reason for not allowing two isolated scope on the two directives, is that the view would not know where to get the scope values from, if a scope variable had the same name in the two isolated directive controllers

Here is an interesting read: [Why can't multiple directives ask for an isolated scope on the same element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485848/why-cant-multiple-directives-ask-for-an-isolated-scope-on-the-same-element)

Comment: This however doesn't actually create multiple controllers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352649/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-directives-on-the-same-html-element "If multiple directives on the same element request a new scope, only one new scope is created"

Comment: The two controllers could share the same scope, which is often the desired effect; one of the two controller can request a new scope, but you cannot have two new scopes;

Comment: @Manube relative to the reasons for not allowing it, wouldn't it happen when you have nested controllers?

Comment: @Drumnbassn nested controllers share $scope via prototypal inheritance; see http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html   so I believe there is no dilemna in that case; as opposed to two isolated scopes applying to the same element (which angularjs will not allow, to avoid erratic behaviour: only one directive per element can have an isolated scope)

Answer (score 32):

You could extend a controller and use it wherever you like.  See the Fiddle for a better example.

```
<script>
var multiApp = angular.module('new', []);

multiApp.controller('aCtrl', ['$scope', '$controller', function ($scope, $controller) {
  $scope.text1 = 'Hello';

  angular.extend(this, $controller('bCtrl', {$scope: $scope}));
}]);



multiApp.controller('bCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.text2 = 'World!';
}]);
</script>
```

With html like:

```
<body ng-app="new">
    <div id="container1" ng-controller="aCtrl">
        {{text1}} {{text2}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkelly/thk9n20o/#base.com

Comment: I found this quite useful as it basically allows multiple controlers on the same element. My purpose was simply to break up the controllers for organization while sharing the scope and this was perfect for that.

Answer (score 8):

### No

HTML is a form of XML, and it is not valid xml to have multiple non-unique attributes on the same element. In other words,

```
<div ng-controller="a" ng-controller="b">
```

is invalid. But what about when we do

```
<div id="a" ng-controller="a">
    <div id="b" ng-controller="b">
        <div id="c">
```

This *is* valid xml/HTML, *but* it is not assigning two controllers to the `div` with id `c`. This is called Nested Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been faced with the same problem trying to code the tabs with container and I'm going to use a directive, which wraps the content using `ng-transclude` - this way it will be just one controller for the content and I'll then define another controller on the directive, which can be re-used multiple times with whatever content necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="LukApp1">
        <div ng-controller="LukCon1">
            <textarea ng-model="text1" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
            <textarea ng-model="text2" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="LukCon2">
            <textarea ng-model="text3" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
            <textarea ng-model="text4" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
var app = angular.module("LukApp1", []);
app.controller("LukCon1", function($scope) {
  $scope.text1 = "First Controller TEXT1";
  $scope.text2 = "First Controller TEXT2";
});
app.controller("LukCon2", function($scope) {
  $scope.text3 = "Second Controller TEXT3";
  $scope.text4 = "Second Controller TEXT4";
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, which is about applying two of more controllers on the *same* one element, not on two different ones.

Answer (score 0):

this is surely gonna work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myNgApp">
    <div id="div1" ng-controller="anotherController">
        Message: {{message}} <br />       
        <div id="div2" ng-controller="myController">
            Message: {{message}}
        </div>
    </div>

      <div id="div3" ng-controller="myController">
        Message: {{message}}
    </div>

      <div id="div4" ng-controller="anotherController">
        Message: {{message}}
    </div>

    <script>
        var ngApp = angular.module('myNgApp', []);

        ngApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "This is myController";       
        });

        ngApp.controller('anotherController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "This is anotherController";       
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```