# angularjs many controllers ng design material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Ng-design-material requiers a controller to manage ui component. But I also need a controller on the same page to manage user data and logics (such as input or timer). 
According this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638823/is-it-possible-to-apply-multiple-angularjs-controllers-on-the-same-element), it's not possible to have two controllers in the same element. 
So the question is, what could be the best practice, better solution to do what I want ?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEgYwd

```
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', function($scope, $mdSidenav){

  $scope.data = "";

  $scope.toggleRight = function() {
     $mdSidenav('right').toggle()
       .then(function(){
         $log.debug("toggle RIGHT is done");
      })}
}]);
```

In the example above, "data" should be somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better thing would do attach click event using directive `md-button` with `E`

**Directive**

```
app.directive('mdButton', function($log, $mdSidenav){
  return{
    restric: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.on('click', function(){
        $mdSidenav('right').toggle()
         .then(function(){
           $log.debug("toggle RIGHT is done");
           scope.$eval(attrs.action); //you could pass any method which you want to run
        })
      });
    }
  }
});
```

[**Working Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwOowq)